# Can't add CircularSeekBar to my project

Tags: java, android, xml

Hey,

I've been trying for hours to add [this](https://github.com/devadvance/circularseekbar) to my project to make a fuel gauge.
I've been doing everything as it is shown in the instructions. But I happen to encounter some problems that I can't resolve.

I've pasted the .java file as instructed [evidence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkzSp.png) but I get 2 problems here. First the "gradle" folder is highlighted in red and the .java file in question has a red J in its icon. I've tried to search how to solve those but nothing works for me.
I don't know if the next problem is because of the previous ones but when I try to add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.devadvance.circulartest"`
in the parent view in xml file i get the error to use `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` to "automatically" search for the custom view but it doesn't work. So I can't import the .java in the activity(its like its not there") and I can't use it in the layout file.

Please help I've tried searching on SO but I could't find anything to work for me.

Beginner android dev here :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. First, it's great that you've tried searching SO for an answer. Not many beginners do that. You should read the help section and especially the part about how to ask. In particular, I'd recommend adding the problem source code to the question instead of linking a picture. Also, if you have two potentially unrelated problems, ask two questions.

Comment: I got it to work. To remove to red J in the icon of the .java file I removed the folders that I made in finder and created them again using the Android studio + because I have the package name com.example.%MYNAME&.%APPNAME% it didn't work if I put it in the com.example.%APPNAME%. So I'm an idiot xD
Any way thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to use your given customseekbar in a basic hello world app. It works perfectly fine for me.

I see you've put the `com/devadvance/circulerseekbar/circularseekbar.java` in the src folder instead of main/java. So it should be in `src/main/java/com/devadvance/circulerseekbar/circularseekbar.java.`

Also I found out that you don't really need to add the namespace `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.devadvance.circulartest` instead the default namespace of `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto` in the xml file should be fine.

Finally, don't forget to add import `com.myapplication.R;` in the customseekbar class to use your resource class R in the customseekbar class.

Hope it helps, otherwise let me know!

[image]